# How to find the null hypothesis in a two sample test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, multiple-comparisons

I am new to hypothesis testing. I would like to solve some questions to improve my knowledge. I did well, but am not sure about this one.

I do not really understand part a. How can we examine the standard deviation? For me, I see that the standard deviation of the first sample is higher than the other one, but there is no relationship between them. Am I correct?

For part b, I think the null hypothesis is:

$$H_0:\mu_1 - \mu_2 \ge 7750.$$

Is that correct?

> The Washington Post Weekly Edition quoted an Urban Institute study
> that stated that about 80% of the estimated \$200 billion of federal
> housing subsidies consisted of tax breaks (mainly deductions for
> mortgage interest payments). Samples indicated that the federal
> housing benefits average was \$8,268 for those with incomes between
> \$200,000 and \$500,000 and only \$365 for those with incomes of \$40,000
> to \$50,000. The respective standard deviations were \$2,100 and \$150. They were obtained from sample sizes of 150.
>
> a.     Examine the sample standard deviations. What do these suggest
> is the relationship between the two population standard deviations?
> Support your assertion.
>
> b.    Conduct a hypothesis test to determine if the average federal
> housing benefits are at least \$7,750 more for those in the \$200,000 to
> \$500,000 income range. Use a 0.05 significance level.
>
> c.     Having reached your decision in part b, state the type of
> statistical error that could have been made by you.